# Airflow backfill only 13 instances are run with default setup

Tags: python, airflow

I am experimenting with [airbnb airflow](https://github.com/airbnb/airflow). While I am trying to run it with 'backfill' option for one day with timedelta of 60 minutes, only 13 instances are executed. Rest are shown as waiting and never executed.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more info like which Airflow version is and which Executor you defined in the "airflow.cfg".

For `CeleryExecutor`, you have to have "airflow worker" running together with the scheduler.

Also your DAG may be pending if your ending date (`"-e END_DATE"`) has reached.